# Two Kafa Consumers with one producer and one partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have One producer and Two consumers with single partition . I preferred this case for handling heavy load balance on producer. But my two consumers get same data on every producer emit. I want one consumer should get data once and other should idle. Please suggest me solution.

Comment: This is not the platform to ask this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: How many partitions does the topic have?

Comment: I think OP has misunderstood partition assignment. Kafka assigns a partition to a consumer. On the other hand, one consumer can listen to many partitions. For more information check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891414/kafka-partition-and-throughput/54895528#54895528

Answer (score 1):

**I want one consumer should get data once and other should idle. ?**

If you want load balancing between consumers then they should belongs to same group, so add same `group.id` for both the consumers

## [Consumers](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers)

> Consumers label themselves with a consumer group name, and each record published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing consumer group. Consumer instances can be in separate processes or on separate machines.

**If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then the records will effectively be load balanced over the consumer instances.**

**If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then each record will be broadcast to all the consumer processes.**

Comment: I used same group for both the consumers but still both consumers getting same data.